# How to show pdf in browser and allow to download/open it by adobe reader?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I need to make possible to preview the pdf file in the browser window for example in  and to make some button which allow to open it in Adobe Reader program for edit purpose.

The problem I encountered is that if browser know how to treat PDF's files it will not allow me to download it, and always open it in a new tab. and if I config browser not to open PDF file inside browser it allow me to download file but it will not show me the PDF inside

any body have some Idea how can i combine this two requirements in one html page?

i need the solution for Internet Explorer 11

Comment: As best of my knowledge there is no option as you want

Comment: You can open the pdf in an Iframe

Comment: Yes, but if i open pdf in an Iframe, i can not open it in adobe reader in any way, because browser always will open it in another tab

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but there's a bit of plumbing involved. Basically, you don't link to the PDF directly, you link to an HTML page that uses an object element to display the PDF in most of the window. You can then have a header that holds a button that calls a JavaScript to fetch the PDF and save it locally. My example uses download2.js for that part. It even works in IE 11 though I don't think it will work in anything lower than IE 8.

See the example at the URL below.
http://practicalpdf.com/solutions/practicalpdf/preview-with-button/wrapper-with-button.html